# Parse selected values from XML in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing

I have the following XML file (I put here only a short scheme), it's a SEPA XML bank statement. I'm not familiar with parsing XML files, my next move will be inserting and comparing to data stored in the SQL databases for error checks. Sadly, I know what to do next, don't know how to make progress with my first step. All I need is to create a table to select values of 2 attributes from a file stored at a particular place

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02">
  <BkToCstmrStmt>
    <GrpHdr>
      ..........
    </GrpHdr>
    <Stmt>
      <Ntry>
        <Amt Ccy="EUR">RequestedAmount1</Amt>
        <AddtlNtryInf>RequestedInfo1</AddtlNtryInf>
      </Ntry>
      <Ntry>
        <Amt Ccy="EUR">RequestedAmount2</Amt>
        <AddtlNtryInf>RequestedInfo2</AddtlNtryInf>
      </Ntry>
      <Ntry>
        <Amt Ccy="EUR">RequestedAmount3</Amt>
        <AddtlNtryInf>RequestedInfo3</AddtlNtryInf>
      </Ntry>
    </Stmt>
  </BkToCstmrStmt>
</Document>
```

If the XML structure was simpler, for example like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Ntry>
  <Amt Ccy="EUR">RequestedAmount1</Amt>
  <AddtlNtryInf>RequestedInfo1</AddtlNtryInf>
</Ntry>
<Ntry>
  <Amt Ccy="EUR">RequestedAmount2</Amt>
  <AddtlNtryInf>RequestedInfo2</AddtlNtryInf>
</Ntry>
<Ntry>
  <Amt Ccy="EUR">RequestedAmount3</Amt>
  <AddtlNtryInf>RequestedInfo3</AddtlNtryInf>
</Ntry>
```

...then I'd use this query to select requested attributes Amt and AddtlNtryInf and it works perfectly

```
SELECT
   MY_XML.Ntry.query('Amt').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(255)') AS Amt,
   MY_XML.Ntry.query('AddtlNtryInf').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(255)') AS AddtlNtryInf
FROM (SELECT CAST(MY_XML AS xml)
      FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\tmp\TestSqlSimple.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)) AS T(MY_XML)
      CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('Ntry') AS MY_XML (Ntry);
```

But don't know how to deal with that more complicated one. I've tried something like this and several similar attempts but I failed because it doesn't select anything, the result is nothing

```
SELECT
   MY_XML.Ntry.query('Amt').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(255)') AS Amt,
   MY_XML.Ntry.query('AddtlNtryInf').value('.', 'NVARCHAR(255)') AS AddtlNtryInf
FROM (SELECT CAST(MY_XML AS xml)
      FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\tmp\TestSqlSimple.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS T(MY_XML)) AS T(MY_XML)
      CROSS APPLY MY_XML.nodes('/Document/BkToCstmrStmt/Stmt/Ntry') AS MY_XML (Ntry);
```

Can't figure out what to do with that CROSS APPLY. Thank you very much for any suggestions or improvements, you're doing a great job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there.

(1) The XML file has a default namespace, and it needs a special treatment via `XMLNAMESPACES` clause.

(2) The **Amt** element probably has a numeric value so you could use `DECIMAL(x,y)` data type. But I kept the `NVARCHAR(255)` to match the obfuscated XML file example.

(3) The SQL below is using `.value()` method without unnecessary `.query()` method.

(4) It is a good practice to use `elementName/text()` technique for performance reasons. It is MS SQL Server specific peculiarity.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
   ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
   Amt NVARCHAR(255),
   AddtlNtryInf NVARCHAR(255)
);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02') 
    , XmlFile (xmlData) AS
(
   SELECT TRY_CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) 
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'e:\Temp\TestSqlSimple.xml', CODEPAGE = '65001', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
)
INSERT INTO @tbl (Amt, AddtlNtryInf)
SELECT c.value('(Amt/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)') AS Amt
    , c.value('(AddtlNtryInf/text())[1]', 'NVARCHAR(255)') AS AddtlNtryInf
FROM XmlFile CROSS APPLY xmlData.nodes('/Document/BkToCstmrStmt/Stmt/Ntry') AS t(c);

-- test
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

Comment: Did you say 'you're almost there'? :D not at all but thanks to you I am. Thank you soooo much for your advice, that was absolutely brilliant and I totally appreciate it. Yes, the data type isn't important for me at this point, I was struggling with the whole select. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
declare @doc xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02">
  <BkToCstmrStmt>
    <GrpHdr>
      ..........
    </GrpHdr>
    <Stmt>
      <Ntry>
        <Amt Ccy="EUR">RequestedAmount1</Amt>
        <AddtlNtryInf>RequestedInfo1</AddtlNtryInf>
      </Ntry>
      <Ntry>
        <Amt Ccy="EUR">RequestedAmount2</Amt>
        <AddtlNtryInf>RequestedInfo2</AddtlNtryInf>
      </Ntry>
      <Ntry>
        <Amt Ccy="EUR">RequestedAmount3</Amt>
        <AddtlNtryInf>RequestedInfo3</AddtlNtryInf>
      </Ntry>
    </Stmt>
  </BkToCstmrStmt>
 </Document>';

with xmlnamespaces (DEFAULT 'urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.02')  
select s.Stmt.value('(GrpHdr)[1]', 'varchar(200)') GrpHdr,
       n.Ntry.value('(Amt)[1]', 'varchar(200)') Amt,
       n.Ntry.value('(AddtlNtryInf)[1]', 'varchar(200)') AddtlNtryInf
from @doc.nodes('/Document/BkToCstmrStmt') s(Stmt)
outer apply s.Stmt.nodes('Stmt/Ntry') n(Ntry)
```

Comment: Thank you David so much for this query, you taught me an alternative approach and it helped me a lot. It works perfectly. You're doing a great job